# Wildfly deployed war successfully on remote server but 404 not found

Tags: maven, amazon-ec2, wildfly, war, web-deployment

I have successfully deployed my project using:

*mvn wildfly:deploy
-Dwildfly-hostname=ec2-54-152-40-62.compute-1.amazonaws.com -Dmaven.test.skip=true*

I can see the my project, aigateway.war from wildfly admin deployments section at:

*ec2-54-152-40-62.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9990*

And all my front-end code are located in webapp folder.

But when I go to

*ec2-54-152-40-62.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/aigateway/index.html*

I got a 404 not found. I don't know what is going on. And everything works perfect on my local machine.

I am working with **wildfly 10.1.0.Final, hibernate ogm 5.0.10.Final and Cassandra 3.0.9**

Here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>aigateway</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>
                com.sensorhound.aigateway.ws.filters.CORSFilter
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sensorhound</groupId>
    <artifactId>aigateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jetty.version>9.3.12.v20160915</jetty.version>
        <jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
        <ogm.version>5.0.4.Final</ogm.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.0.4.Final</hibernate.version>
        <wildfly-hostname>SPECIFY</wildfly-hostname>
        <wildfly-user>wildfly-deployer</wildfly-user>
        <wildfly-password>Gelert1!</wildfly-password>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-infinispan</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-cassandra</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
           <version>1.6.1</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- hibernate ogm -->
        <!-- Hibernate OGM Infinispan module; pulls in the OGM core module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-infinispan</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- standard APIs dependencies - provided in a Java EE container -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add the Narayana Transactions Manager
         an implementation would be provided in a Java EE container,
         but this works nicely in Java SE as well -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.narayana.jta</groupId>
            <artifactId>narayana-jta</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-spi</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId> <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId> 
            <version>${jetty.version}</version> </dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fusesource.leveldbjni</groupId>
            <artifactId>leveldbjni-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codehaus</id>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-nexus</id>
            <name>Kundera Public Repository</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>kundera-missing</id>
            <name>Kundera Public Missing Resources Repository</name>
            <url>http://kundera.googlecode.com/svn/maven2/maven-missing-resources</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>aigateway</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>git submodule update</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>git</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>submodule</argument>
                                <argument>update</argument>
                                <argument>--init</argument>
                                <argument>--recursive</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Alpha1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <force>true</force>
                    <hostname>${wildfly-hostname}</hostname>
                    <username>${wildfly-user}</username>
                    <password>${wildfly-password}</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the server.log from wildfly:

```
2017-03-30 21:34:16,073 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-3) Configured system properties:
    [Standalone] = 
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    file.encoding = UTF-8
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = /
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.headless = true
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.print.PSPrinterJob
    java.class.path = /opt/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
    java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
    java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
    java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
    java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
    java.runtime.name = OpenJDK Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~14.04-b14
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 1.8.0_91
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 25.91-b14
    javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
    javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
    javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
    jboss.home.dir = /opt/wildfly
    jboss.host.name = ip-172-31-55-197
    jboss.modules.dir = /opt/wildfly/modules
    jboss.modules.system.pkgs = org.jboss.byteman
    jboss.node.name = ip-172-31-55-197
    jboss.qualified.host.name = ip-172-31-55-197.ec2.internal
    jboss.server.base.dir = /opt/wildfly/standalone
    jboss.server.config.dir = /opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration
    jboss.server.data.dir = /opt/wildfly/standalone/data
    jboss.server.deploy.dir = /opt/wildfly/standalone/data/content
    jboss.server.log.dir = /opt/wildfly/standalone/log
    jboss.server.name = ip-172-31-55-197
    jboss.server.persist.config = true
    jboss.server.temp.dir = /opt/wildfly/standalone/tmp
    line.separator = 

    logging.configuration = file:/opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
    module.path = /opt/wildfly/modules
    org.jboss.boot.log.file = /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log
    org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
    org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Linux
    os.version = 3.13.0-91-generic
    path.separator = :
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.class.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/classes
    sun.boot.library.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = 
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.command = /opt/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar -mp /opt/wildfly/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/wildfly -Djboss.server.base.dir=/opt/wildfly/standalone -c standalone.xml
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level = unknown
    user.country = US
    user.dir = /opt/wildfly-10.1.0.Final
    user.home = /home/wildfly
    user.language = en
    user.name = wildfly
    user.timezone = Etc/UTC
2017-03-30 21:34:16,075 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-3) VM Arguments: -D[Standalone] -Xms64m -Xmx1024m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties 
2017-03-30 21:34:17,880 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
2017-03-30 21:34:18,725 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDM0004: The realm name of the defined security realm 'SSLRealm' does not match the realm name within the properties file 'ApplicationRealm'.
2017-03-30 21:34:25,804 WARN  [org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HHH000409: Using org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator which does not generate IETF RFC 4122 compliant UUID values; consider using org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator instead
2017-03-30 21:34:25,940 WARN  [org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Unrecognized hbm2ddl_auto value : none.  Supported values include create, create-drop, update, and validate.  Ignoring
2017-03-30 21:34:27,285 WARN  [org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.ConfigContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HSEARCH000075: Configuration setting hibernate.search.lucene_version was not specified: using LUCENE_CURRENT.
2017-03-30 21:34:27,635 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry apache-cassandra-clientutil-3.5.jar in /content/sensorcloud-2.2.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/cassandra-all-3.5.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2017-03-30 21:34:27,635 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry apache-cassandra-thrift-3.5.jar in /content/sensorcloud-2.2.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/cassandra-all-3.5.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2017-03-30 21:34:27,737 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar in /content/sensorcloud-2.2.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb-2.3.2.jbossorg-4.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2017-03-30 21:34:27,738 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar in /content/sensorcloud-2.2.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb-2.3.2.jbossorg-4.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2017-03-30 21:34:27,738 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry concurrent-1.3.2.jar in /content/sensorcloud-2.2.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb-2.3.2.jbossorg-4.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2017-03-30 21:34:27,738 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry antlr-2.7.2.jar in /content/sensorcloud-2.2.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb-2.3.2.jbossorg-4.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2017-03-30 21:34:28,542 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYEJB0463: Invalid transaction attribute type REQUIRED on SFSB lifecycle method Method init() of class class com.sensorhound.aigateway.db.daos.IOConfigurationDAO, valid types are REQUIRES_NEW and NOT_SUPPORTED. Method will be treated as NOT_SUPPORTED.
2017-03-30 21:34:28,542 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYEJB0463: Invalid transaction attribute type REQUIRED on SFSB lifecycle method Method end() of class class com.sensorhound.aigateway.db.daos.IOConfigurationDAO, valid types are REQUIRES_NEW and NOT_SUPPORTED. Method will be treated as NOT_SUPPORTED.
2017-03-30 21:34:28,544 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYEJB0463: Invalid transaction attribute type REQUIRED on SFSB lifecycle method Method init() of class class com.sensorhound.aigateway.db.CassandraDAO, valid types are REQUIRES_NEW and NOT_SUPPORTED. Method will be treated as NOT_SUPPORTED.
2017-03-30 21:34:28,544 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYEJB0463: Invalid transaction attribute type REQUIRED on SFSB lifecycle method Method end() of class class com.sensorhound.aigateway.db.CassandraDAO, valid types are REQUIRES_NEW and NOT_SUPPORTED. Method will be treated as NOT_SUPPORTED.
2017-03-30 21:34:30,200 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) RESTEASY002155: Provider class com.sensorhound.aigateway.ws.filters.CORSFilter is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
2017-03-30 21:34:31,680 WARN  [org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.GroupRuleStatus
2017-03-30 21:34:31,680 WARN  [org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): com.sensorhound.common.domain.impl.GroupRuleStatus
2017-03-30 21:35:03,328 WARN  [org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Unrecognized hbm2ddl_auto value : none.  Supported values include create, create-drop, update, and validate.  Ignoring
2017-03-30 21:35:03,352 WARN  [org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.ConfigContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) HSEARCH000075: Configuration setting hibernate.search.lucene_version was not specified: using LUCENE_CURRENT.
2017-03-30 21:35:03,559 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYEJB0463: Invalid transaction attribute type REQUIRED on SFSB lifecycle method Method init() of class class com.sensorhound.aigateway.db.CassandraDAO, valid types are REQUIRES_NEW and NOT_SUPPORTED. Method will be treated as NOT_SUPPORTED.
2017-03-30 21:35:03,560 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYEJB0463: Invalid transaction attribute type REQUIRED on SFSB lifecycle method Method end() of class class com.sensorhound.aigateway.db.CassandraDAO, valid types are REQUIRES_NEW and NOT_SUPPORTED. Method will be treated as NOT_SUPPORTED.
2017-03-30 21:35:03,560 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYEJB0463: Invalid transaction attribute type REQUIRED on SFSB lifecycle method Method init() of class class com.sensorhound.aigateway.db.daos.IOConfigurationDAO, valid types are REQUIRES_NEW and NOT_SUPPORTED. Method will be treated as NOT_SUPPORTED.
2017-03-30 21:35:03,560 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYEJB0463: Invalid transaction attribute type REQUIRED on SFSB lifecycle method Method end() of class class com.sensorhound.aigateway.db.daos.IOConfigurationDAO, valid types are REQUIRES_NEW and NOT_SUPPORTED. Method will be treated as NOT_SUPPORTED.
2017-03-30 21:35:03,624 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) RESTEASY002155: Provider class com.sensorhound.aigateway.ws.filters.CORSFilter is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
```

If you need more information, I am willing to share.

Thanks!

Comment: Seem apache is listening on port 8080 not Wildfly `Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at ec2-54-152-40-62.compute-1.amazonaws.com Port 8080`

Comment: This doesn't look like the full log, but try `ec2-54-152-40-62.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/sensorcloud-2.2.1-SNAPSHOT/index.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed this problem. The problem is that my apache server is using port 8080. And my co-worker changed the wildfly server http port to 28080, and that doesn't work at all. So, yeah, make sure to do a **sudo netstat -peanut** to find out which program is listening to which port before trying to access the page.